# Terraria character gone missing?

Tags: terraria

A few days ago my friends invited me to a server in Terraria with them, as I had the most knowledge out of them, and as such I made a new character in order to make it fair.
A few days of playing on the server and we're all having fun until my old laptop malfunctions. One of the boards were completely fried and as I've had that laptop for the past 3 years, instead of getting it repaired, I decided to buy an entirely new laptop.
I went through the usual boot up process and re-downloaded all of my apps when my friends invited me back. I clicked "join game" under my friends profile and it brought up the screen to select your character, but my newer one wasn't there, only my two older ones. I looked up how to fix the problem but there were no back-ups in the Terraria player files of my laptop.

Is this character lost to time or is there another glimmer of hope?

Comment: If you used steam, steam only synchronizes your game data with the cloud after you closed the game(as far as I know). so if you created your new character, played it and then your computer crashed, it properly wasn't synchronized to the steam cloud. How about copying it manually from your old hard disc?

Answer (score 0):

You could take your old laptop to a repair shop and ask for them to backup your files. Other than that there is nothing you can do without a cloud backup.

Answer (score 0):

Terraria (vanilla) servers **don't store** any character data.

If you haven't explicitly marked the character as "*Stored in the Cloud*" using the button in the image below, your only chance will be retrieving the character file in your old computer's hard drive.

[image: The Move to cloud button, when a character is stored locally]

[image: The Move off cloud button, when a character is stored on Steam Cloud]

Answer (score 0):

Characters are **not** saved in your steam cloud save by default. Players are stored in your game directory as a .plr file with all of the character's data. You can somewhat retrieve your player by going to https://yal.cc/r/terrasavr/ and filling your player data if you can remember it. To store future players on the cloud, you can click the cloud icon on a player in the player select menu to store them in your cloud save.